# Annotation present: still no bean found in testing

Tags: java, spring

The class

```
@Component
public class PropertyReader {

    public PropertyReader() {
    }

    @Value("${spring.active.profiles")
    private String profile;

    @Nonnull
    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }
}
```

The Test

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)

public class PropertyReaderTest {

    @Autowired
    private PropertyReader propertyReader;
    @Test
    public void testGetProfile() throws Exception {
        System.out.printf(System.getProperty("spring.active.profiles"));
        assertEquals("development", propertyReader.getProfile());
    }
}
```

The dependency

```
     <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Test Fails

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.yahoo.pryme_services.external_services.ifs.PropertyReader com.yahoo.pryme_services.external_services.ifs.PropertyReaderTest.propertyReader; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.yahoo.pryme_services.external_services.ifs.PropertyReader] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

What am I missing?

P.S. A day old with Spring

Answer (score -1):

fixed

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = PropertyReader.class,loader=AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)

public class PropertyReaderTest {

    @Autowired
    private PropertyReader propertyReader;
    @Test
    public void testGetProfile() throws Exception {
        System.out.printf(System.getProperty("spring.active.profiles"));
        assertEquals("development", propertyReader.getProfile());
    }
}
```

and

```
@Component
public class PropertyReader {

    public PropertyReader() {
    }

    @Value("#{systemProperties['spring.active.profiles']}")
    private String profile;

    @Nonnull
    public String getProfile() {
        return profile;
    }
}
```